# input validation with two regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi all I have following code: [my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-herschel-sn826)

I have 2 inputs and 2 regex for each of them

```
   <input type="text" id="FormField_6_input" placeholder="company name" />
   <input type="text" id="FormField_13_input" placeholder="zip code" />

      const companyRGEX = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+,-]*(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_,.+-]*){2,}$/;
      const found = event.target.value.match(companyRGEX);

      const zipRGEX = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,9}$/;
      const foundZip = event.target.value.match(zipRGEX);
```

I need to check

1. if company name is valid but zip is not valid then disable button and show error message for zip
2. if zip code is valid but compony name is not valid then disable button and show error message for company name
3. if both of them is not valid then then disable button and show both error messages

I write my code only for company name with one regex and it was work very well, for example:

```
 function validat(event) {
           const companyRGEX = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+,-]*(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_,.+-]*){2,}$/;
           const found = event.target.value.match(companyRGEX);
           const errorMSG = document.getElementById("errorMSG");

          if (button && (found || !event.target.value)) {
            button.disabled = false;
             errorMSG.style.display = "none";
           } else {
             button.disabled = true;
             errorMSG.style.display = "block";
           }
         }
```

But when I try to write multi check something going wrong, please help me to resolve this problem.
here is multicheck code:

```
    function validate(event) {
      const companyRGEX = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+,-]*(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_,.+-]*){2,}$/;
      const found = event.target.value.match(companyRGEX);

      const zipRGEX = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,9}$/;
      const foundZip = event.target.value.match(zipRGEX);

      if (
        button &&
        (found || !event.target.value) &&
        (foundZip || !event.target.value)
      ) {
        if (button && (found || !event.target.value)) {
          button.disabled = true;
          zip_errorMSG.style.display = "none";
          errorMSG.style.display = "block";
        } else if (button && (foundZip || !event.target.value)) {
          button.disabled = true;
          errorMSG.style.display = "none";
          zip_errorMSG.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          button.disabled = false;
          errorMSG.style.display = "none";
          zip_errorMSG.style.display = "none";
        }
      } else {
        button.disabled = true;
        zip_errorMSG.style.display = "block";
        errorMSG.style.display = "block";
      }
     }
```

P.S. please don't change html, only change js.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const checkvalue = (value, regex) => !!value.match(regex);

    function validateCompanyName(event, source) {
      const companyRGEX = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+,-]*(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_,.+-]*){2,}$/;
      const zipRGEX = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,9}$/;

      const companyIsCorrect = checkvalue(
        companyNameField.value,
        companyRGEX
      );
      const zipIsCorrect = checkvalue(zipPostalCode.value, zipRGEX);

    
      if (button && zipIsCorrect && companyIsCorrect) {
        button.disabled = false;
        zip_errorMSG.style.display = "none";
        errorMSG.style.display = "none";
      } else if (button && !zipIsCorrect && companyIsCorrect) {
        button.disabled = true;
        zip_errorMSG.style.display = "block";
        errorMSG.style.display = "none";
      } else if (button && zipIsCorrect && !companyIsCorrect) {
        button.disabled = true;
        zip_errorMSG.style.display = "none";
        errorMSG.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        button.disabled = true;
        zip_errorMSG.style.display = "block";
        errorMSG.style.display = "block";
      }
```